# Thread error: Because of websocket connection

Tags: python, multithreading, websocket

I have this async function `bar_data_handler(data)` which pings me every minute.

It has a websocket connection

I have been trying to start a function in a new Thread

```
async def bar_data_handler(data):
          print (date)
          t = Thread(target=trading(arg1,arg2), args=(1, 2, 3))
```

Then get this error

***data websocket error, restarting connection: no close frame received or sent***

within the `t = Thread(target=trading(arg1,arg2), args=(1, 2, 3))`

I just wanted to call a function "trading(arg1,arg2)" without blocking the next ping in " async bar_data_handler(data)"

THX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is CALLING `trading` inline, and passing its return value as the thread target.  You need:

```
        t = Thread(target=trading, args=(arg1,arg2))
```